# Alert if span text isn't 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I need to check if the value inside a span isn't 0, if not 0 I want jquery to alert me.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="./flash.php" class="button dark">Flash:
<span style="color:#15B64C;">0</span> </a>
```

So if in that span the value is different than zero I want to show a message with alert.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Post the jQuery script that you have tried here and we'll help you out from there

Comment: the problem is that I can't reach that span... I've tried something like:

if ($(".button dark").children.text() != "0")
{
    alert("sdsad");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is find the span contains 0 value in it by using `:contains` code as following, Try this code :

```
   var span_val = parseInt($('span:contains(0)').text());
        or (any of this)
   var span_val = parseInt($('.button').find('span').text()); 

   if(span_val !== 0)
   {
     alert('No');
   }
   else
   {
     alert('yes');
   }
```

Comment: @luidgi27 This answer was made based on your sample code. For the actual code, its depend on your html structure. Anyway, glad it work!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.button span').each(function ()
{
     if($(this).text().indexOf('0') != -1)
     {
       alert("Yes");
     }
     else
     {
       alert ("No");
     }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the above: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/19/